# Cannot find source of small memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, heap-memory

I created a program that can solve sudoku puzzles in C++ using a brute force backtracking algorithm, however after analyzing the memory usage in valgrind I noticed that it has a small leak. I am aware of a GCC bug that accounts for 1 missed free and 72,704 bytes that are still reachable.

It seems that I am missing 903 `free()` / `delete` / `delete[]` calls that accounts for around 100KB of memory.

Does anyone know what is causing the memory leak and how I can fix it?

Backtracker.cpp

```
#include "Backtracker.h"

/**
 * Clears all dynamic memory in the list.
 * @param lst: the pointer to the list to be cleared
 */
static void clearList(std::list<Grid*> *lst) {
    std::list<Grid*>::iterator it;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lst->size(); i++) {
        it = lst->begin();
        std::advance(it, i);
        delete *it;
    }
    delete lst;
}

/**
 * Solves the sudoku puzzle or returns a null if there is no solution.
 * @param g: a pointer to the starting grid
 * @return: a pointer to the solution
 */
Grid* solve(Grid *g) {
    if (g->isGoal()) {
        return g;
    }

    std::list<Grid*> *successors = g->getSuccessors();
    std::list<Grid*>::iterator it;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < successors->size(); i++) {
        it = successors->begin();
        std::advance(it, i);

        if ((*it)->isValid()) {
            Grid *solution = solve(*it);
            if (solution != nullptr) {
                solution = solution->copyGrid();
                clearList(successors);
                return solution;
            }
        }
    }
    clearList(successors);

    return nullptr;
}`
```

Grid.cpp

```
#include "Grid.h"

/**
 * Constructor for the Grid class.
 */
Grid::Grid() {
    grid = new int*[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        grid[i] = new int[SIZE];
    }

    currRow = 0;
    currCol = 0;
}

/**
 * Destructor for the Grid class.
 */
Grid::~Grid() {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        delete[] grid[i];
    }

    delete[] grid;
}

/**
 * Getter for any value in the grid.
 * @param row: the index of the row
 * @param col: the index of the column
 * @return: the value at the given row and column indexes
 */
int Grid::getValue(int row, int col) {
    return grid[row][col];
}

/**
 * Setter for any value in the grid.
 * @param row: the index of the row
 * @param col: the index of the column
 * @param value: the value to set at the given row and column
 */
void Grid::setValue(int row, int col, int value) {
    grid[row][col] = value;
}

/**
 * Allocates dynamic memory for a new grid and copies over the contents.
 * @return: a pointer to the new grid object
 */
Grid* Grid::copyGrid() {
    Grid *copy = new Grid();

    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
            copy->setValue(r, c, grid[r][c]);
        }
    }

    copy->currRow = currRow;
    copy->currCol = currCol;

    return copy;
}

/**
 * Creates a list of successors by moving the cursor and setting the next value.
 * @return: a list of the successors
 */
std::list<Grid*>* Grid::getSuccessors() {
    std::list<Grid*> *successors = new std::list<Grid*>();

    if (canMove()) {
        Grid *copy = copyGrid();
        copy->moveCursor();
        if (copy->getValue(currRow, currCol) != 0) {
            successors->push_back(copy);
            return successors;
        } else {
            delete copy;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            copy = copyGrid();
            copy->moveCursor();
            copy->setValue(currRow, currCol, i + 1);
            if (copy->isValid()) {
                successors->push_back(copy);
            } else {
                delete copy;
            }
        }
    }

    return successors;
}

/**
 * Determines if the current configuration could be a possible solution.
 * @return: true if it could be a solution, false if not
 */
bool Grid::isValid() {
    // Checks each row for a duplicate number.
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        bool nums[SIZE] = {false * SIZE};
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
            if ((grid[r][c] > 0) && (!nums[grid[r][c] - 1])) {
                nums[grid[r][c] - 1] = true;
            } else if ((grid[r][c] > 0) && (nums[grid[r][c] - 1])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checks each column for a duplicate number.
    for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
        bool nums[SIZE] = {false * SIZE};
        for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
            if ((grid[r][c] > 0) && (!nums[grid[r][c] - 1])) {
                nums[grid[r][c] - 1] = true;
            } else if ((grid[r][c] > 0) && (nums[grid[r][c] - 1])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Checks squares.
    int val;
    for (int sRow = 0; sRow < SQUARES; sRow++) {
        for (int sCol = 0; sCol < SQUARES; sCol++) {
            bool nums[SIZE] = {false * SIZE};
            for (int r = 0; r < SQUARES; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < SQUARES; c++) {
                    val = grid[(sRow * 3) + r][(sCol * 3) + c];
                    if ((val > 0) && (!nums[val - 1])) {
                        nums[val - 1] = true;
                    } else if ((val > 0) && (nums[val - 1])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Determines if the current configuration is a solution or not.
 * @return: true if it is a solution, false if not
 */
bool Grid::isGoal() {
    for (int r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
            if (grid[r][c] <= 0 || grid[r][c] > 9) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return isValid();
}

/**
 * Determines if the cursor can be advanced a position or not.
 * @return: true if the cursor can be moved, false if it is at the last position of the board
 */
bool Grid::canMove() {
    return !((currRow == SIZE - 1) && (currCol == SIZE));
}

/**
 * Moves the cursor to the next position if it is not at the last position of the board.
 * @return: true if the cursor was moved, false if it cannot be moved
 */
bool Grid::moveCursor() {
    if (!canMove()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (currCol != SIZE - 1) {
            currCol++;
            return true;
        } else {
            currCol = 0;
            if (currRow == SIZE - 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                currRow++;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a string for the given row.
 * @param row: the index of the row to generate a string for
 * @return: a string for that row
 */
std::string Grid::rowString(int row) {
    std::string output = "";
    int c;

    for (c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        output += std::to_string(grid[row][c]) + " ";
    }
    output += "| ";

    for (c = 3; c < 6; c++) {
        output += std::to_string(getValue(row, c)) + " ";
    }
    output += "| ";

    for (c = 6; c < SIZE; c++) {
        output += std::to_string(getValue(row, c)) + " ";
    }

    return output;
}

/**
 * Creates a string representation of the entire grid.
 * @return: a string for the entire grid.
 */
std::string Grid::toString() {
    std::string output = "";

    // TODO remove this
    output += std::to_string(currRow) + "," + std::to_string(currCol) + "\n";

    int r;

    for (r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        output += rowString(r) + "\n";
    }
    output += "---------------------\n";

    for (r = 3; r < 6; r++) {
        output += rowString(r) + "\n";
    }
    output += "---------------------\n";

    for (r = 6; r < SIZE; r++) {
        output += rowString(r) + "\n";
    }

    return output;
}`
```

valgrind output

```
==3021== 
==3021== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3021==     in use at exit: 106,488 bytes in 903 blocks
==3021==   total heap usage: 3,260,824 allocs, 3,259,921 frees, 121,174,996 bytes allocated
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 19 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x401A69: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 20 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 21 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 22 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 23 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 26 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 27 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 412 (16 direct, 396 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 28 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x40230F: main (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== 29,664 (1,152 direct, 28,512 indirect) bytes in 72 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 31 of 32
==3021==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3021==    by 0x402620: Grid::copyGrid() (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x404104: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021==    by 0x4040ED: solve(Grid*) (in /home/anthony/Documents/Code/c-c++-projects/Sudoku-Solver/sudoku-solver)
==3021== 
==3021== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3021==    definitely lost: 1,312 bytes in 82 blocks
==3021==    indirectly lost: 32,472 bytes in 820 blocks
==3021==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3021==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==3021==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3021== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3021== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==3021== 
==3021== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3021== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Is it really important? The kernel will free all memory your process allocated anyway, when the application terminates. Actually; freeing the memory yourself may in fact be slower than just leaking it and letting the kernel clean up ;-)

Comment: It isn't that important, I just wanted to understand what is causing it since I am trying to learn C++ on my own.

Comment: That's a fair reason :)

Comment: @AnthonyPalumbo You should not be working with raw pointer so much. The STL offers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, and `std::vector` as a general purpose container (as well as many others). Use them!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the C++ STL, but `clearList` looks suspicious, why do you call `begin()` every loop iteration?

Comment: @AndrewSun I'd guess that is because deleting an element from a list invalidates all iterators.

Comment: @AndrewSun I need to call `begin()` every loop iteration to reset the iterator to the front of the list, I also am not that familiar with the C++ STL but I believe that std::list works somewhat like a linked list.

Comment: @BenSteffan There's no iterator invalidation. They're not altering the list just passing each element to `delete`. They are doing something silly though. Starting at the beginning and taking `i` steps for every element turns what should be a linear iteration into a quadratic operation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Nevermind, you are right. That was stupid of me.

Comment: @Blastfurnace How do you suggest I clear the list more efficiently?

Comment: I'd use a [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop: `for (Grid *ptr : *lst) { delete ptr; }`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it's your problem, but... according to valgrind, the problem is related with memory allocated in `Grid::copyGrid()`, so the memory allocated by the following `new`

```
Grid* Grid::copyGrid() {
    Grid *copy = new Grid();
    // ...
    return copy;
}
```

I suspect the problem (a problem?) is in `solve()`.

```
if ((*it)->isValid()) {
    Grid *solution = solve(*it);
    if (solution != nullptr) {
        solution = solution->copyGrid();
        clearList(successors);
        return solution;
    }
}
```

Observe that `solve()` return a `solution` that is obtained by

```
solution = solution->copyGrid();
```

so an allocated (`new`) value but losing the original value of `solution` obtained by

```
Grid *solution = solve(*it);
```

that come from `solve()` so it's allocated.

I mean: where you delete the value returned by `solve()`?

I suppose you should write something like

```
if ((*it)->isValid()) {
    Grid *solution = solve(*it);
    if (solution != nullptr) {
        Grid *retSol = solution->copyGrid();
        clearList(successors);
        delete solution;
        return retSol;
    }
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP answer:

> I just tried this, however it only causes a segmentation fault. Removing the delete solution; line fixes the segmentation fault, but the memory leak is still there.

I see... 
The problem here is (if I'm not wrong) that `solve()` can also return the value received

```
Grid* solve(Grid *g) {
    if (g->isGoal()) {
        return g;
    }
```

Uhmmm...

So you have to delete it **only** if different from `*it`.

I don't like it but I propose

```
if ((*it)->isValid()) {
    Grid *solution = solve(*it);
    if (solution != nullptr) {
        Grid *retSol = solution->copyGrid();
        clearList(successors);

        if ( solution != *it )
           delete solution;

        return retSol;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, however it only causes a segmentation fault. Removing the delete solution; line fixes the segmentation fault, but the memory leak is still there. Solution does not need to be explicitly deleted because the original is deleted during the clearList function, which is why the solution needs to be copied before clearing the list.

Comment: @AnthonyPalumbo - I see... answer modified